# Nginx: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server

Tags: nginx

I try to start this service but i can´t, the error below occur:

```
root@zabbix:/home/appliance# systemctl status nginx.service

nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-07-25 18:33:26 UTC; 1min 27s ago
  Process: 30040 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 30037 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 25 18:33:25 zabbix nginx[30040]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to [::]:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jul 25 18:33:25 zabbix nginx[30040]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jul 25 18:33:25 zabbix nginx[30040]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to [::]:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jul 25 18:33:26 zabbix nginx[30040]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jul 25 18:33:26 zabbix nginx[30040]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to [::]:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jul 25 18:33:26 zabbix nginx[30040]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Jul 25 18:33:26 zabbix systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1

Jul 25 18:33:26 zabbix systemd[1]: *******Failed to start A high performance web server*** and a reverse proxy server.****

Jul 25 18:33:26 zabbix systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 25 18:33:26 zabbix systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 181):

You already have a process bound to the **HTTP port **80**** (Specially after upgrading systems! it will start apache2 by default)

So try this first :

```
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

If the problem is not solved then run this command **`sudo lsof -i:80`** to get a list of processes using the port and then **stop or disable** web server.

Try to stop the process which are using the port 80 using :

```
sudo fuser -k 80/tcp
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

In some cases it may be some issues in the configuration file.

You can use `nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` command to find any miss-configuration.

In some cases this error is caused by a default Nginx site already on port 80, removing default config works if you don't need a default one.

```
sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: Tnx much, it happend just randomly, maybe someone restarted server machine :)

Comment: LMAO! Best Answer! Specially after upgrading systems! it will start apache2 by default. Thanks dude

Comment: when i use `sudo service apache2 stop` its says `Failed to stop apache2.service: Unit apache2.service not loaded.`

Comment: fuser -k 80/tcp && systemctl restart nginx
this is works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 62):

For me this error was caused by a `default` nginx site already on port 80. Removing default site worked

```
sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: sudo unlink /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

Answer (score 34):

You already have a process bound to the HTTP port 80.
You can run command `sudo lsof -i:80` to get a list of processes using the port and then stop/disable web server.

Answer (score 21):

Try to stop the process which are using the port 80:

```
sudo fuser -k 80/tcp
```

Comment: This will solve the problem now, but at a reboot, if that process is enabled, it will occupy the network port again.

Answer (score 19):

Try to stop the process which is using port 80:

```
sudo fuser -k 80/tcp
```

When you did restart using

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Answer (score 16):

It may be some issues in the configuration file. You can use this 
`nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`command to find any bugs in the configuration file. If you find the bugs resolve that run the `sudo service nginx restart` again. It will work.

[Please check the reference here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/can-t-start-nginx-job-for-nginx-service-failed)

Answer (score 8):

I had to use:

```
sudo killall nginx
```

And could then use;

```
sudo systemctl start nginx
```

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, this error can be triggered in several different situations (which might have the same root, but are perceived as different scenarios).

#### Not only port 80

Depending on your nginx config, you should also try port 443:

- `sudo lsof -i:80`
- `sudo lsof -i:443`

You should be able to check your nginx listen ports in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` (under Debian)

#### Special case

In my case, there was an nginx instance running, that would block itself from restarting. It would not go down with `sudo systemctl stop nginx`. I had to use `sudo killall nginx` and could then use `sudo systemctl start nginx`.

#### Config error

I also experienced the exact same error message on a config error.

You can check your nginx config with `/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf@ (this will also test all virtual host files (`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`)

Answer (score 4):

For me stopping apache service solved the problem
`sudo service apache2 stop`

Answer (score 4):

i had same issue, was because i have apache and nginx on same server !
so when i typed sudo reboot it didn't work because it started apache while am using nginx so i just run this two commands

sudo systemctl stop apache2
then
sudo systemctl start nginx

then  sudo systemctl disable apache2
so next time i reboot not going to face same issue

help from aws services support

Answer (score 3):

I was using gunicorn with nginx, found that service was not active.

```
sudo systemctl enable gunicorn.socket
sudo systemctl start gunicorn.socket
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Worked for me.

if your gunicorn is active, please make sure it's working fine.

you can also go through the logs(errors) via `nginx logs` from

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too. I checked the `/etc/nginx/site-available/default` file and I have forgotten to close the bracket (syntax error).

Answer (score 1):

Just restart the nginx server. It should resolve your problem
`sudo systemctl restart nginx`

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, I tried `sudo systemctl stop nginx` and also attempted to kill the Nginx processes using their PIDs but they were still running and listening on port 80, which indicates that there might be another service or process that is automatically restarting Nginx.

To troubleshoot this issue, I did these steps:

- I identify the parent process by running the following command to identify the parent process of the Nginx processes:

  `ps -o ppid= -p <PID>`

I replaced  with one of the Nginx process IDs.
The output gave me the parent process ID (PPID) for each Nginx process, and `sudo kill <PPID>` solved the issue.

You can also try this:

1. Determine the parent process name: Run the following command to find the name of the parent process: `ps -p <PPID> -o comm=`
   Replace  with the parent process ID obtained in the previous step. Repeat this command for each PPID you have.
   The output will give you the name of the parent process associated with each Nginx process.
2. Stop the parent process: Once you have identified the parent process, try stopping it using the appropriate method. 
   For example, if the parent process is Apache, you can use `sudo systemctl stop apache` or if it is another web server, you can stop it using the corresponding command.

Answer (score 1):

this problem solved by removing nginx then reinstall it by all setting again

then rebooting the system after stopping pache2

```
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

Mine was caused by an inability to find the ssl cert.  I found this by running:

```
nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

This was a permissions issue for me and I did this to "fix" it:

```
sudo chmod 700 /etc/letsencrypt/live/ -R
```